# Loopback extending Access Token model causes problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

Our use case requires that we have two different models for users (provider and consumer). We, therefore, extended the User model into consumer and provider models, but soon ran into trouble when the AccessToken for the provider also started working for the consumer.

Eg. let us assume provider A has a userId of 1 and consumer A has a userId of 1, if provider A logs in and receives an AccessToken, he can then also extract information about a Consumer A by querying the consumer model with his accessToken. This can spell a disaster. ctx.req.accessToken.userId returns 1 in the consumer model for both consumer and provider tokens.

We tried extending the AccessToken Model into AccessTokenProvider and AccessTokenConsumer. Here are the model relations for AccessTokenConsumer

```
"relations": {
 "user": {
 "type": "belongsTo",
 "model": "consumer",
 "foreignKey": "userId"   }   }
```

and for consumer model

```
"relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "AccessTokenConsumer",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true
      }
    }   }
```

However, now ctx.req.accessToken returns null, and logout rest function gives an error of "could not find accessToken"

Answer (score 1):

I tried IvanZh 's answer here [Multiple User child Models problem](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/527).

In node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.js, add `model: userModel.modelName` just after `ttl:ttl` in `User.prototype.createAccessToken` method. Then add the model property to access_token.json. You may have to remigrate the table to database.

Your model name will now be appended to ctx.req.accessToken.model and you can use a conditional to make sure only the correct model type is called.

A word of caution: this will be overwritten if you update Loopback. Frankly, this feature should be built into Loopback, as its absence doesn't add to the charm of a powerful framework that is already marred by deficiencies in the documentation.